# Incrementing variable in AJAX and Flask while automatically reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm using `setInterval()` function to reload information every 5 seconds. The html looks like:

```
<div id = "update"> </div>

<script>
window.setInterval(
     function() {
     $("#update").load("/game");
     }, 5000);
</script>
```

In Flask, my `views.py`:

```
@app.route('/game')
def live_game():
   text = "<p> test </p>"
   return text
```

Now, I'd like to change the variable text every time the page reloads. Something like:

```
counter = 0
@app.route('/game')
def live_game():
   textlist = ['a','b','c','d']         
   text = "<p> "+textlist[counter]+" </p>"
   counter += 1

   return text
```

This obviously doesn't work, as I'm sure I need to be incrementing on the jQuery side, I'm just not sure how. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you need to modify your JavaScript as well as your `views.py`, here are the modifications you should be doing

**HTML**

```
<div id = "update"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var counter = 0;
   window.setInterval(function(){
      $("#update").load("/game?counter=" + counter);
      counter++;
   }, 5000)
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/game")
def live_game():
    textlist = ['a','b','c','d']
    counter = request.args.get('counter')
    return "<p> " + textlist[counter] + " </p>"
```

The output will be

```
<div id = "update"><p> a </p></div>
// after 5 seconds 
<div id = "update"><p> b </p></div>
// and so on
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `/game` flask endpoint in your setInterval function.  Here is much what you need.

```
<script>
window.setInterval(
     function() {
         $.ajax("/game", {dataType:'text', cache: false}).done(function(data){
            $("#update").html(data);}
        );
     }, 5000);
</script>
```

The method will update with whatever the /game endpoint returns.  It is unclear what you intend to be updating or incrementing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm unclear on how this increments through the text list. Do I need to update the function in views.py as well?

Comment: Your existing view code should increment through the test list.